# Typescript: add function to momentjs' prototype

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a function to the momentjs prototype. In Javascript, the code was like this:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(moment()).isWeekend = function() {
    return this.isoWeekday() >= 6;
};
```

How do I do this in typescript? I've read that i need to duplicate the interface and and my function to it, but that's not working:

```
module moment {
    interface Moment {
        isWeekend(): boolean
    }

    Moment.prototype.isWeekend = () => {
        this.isoWeekday() >= 6;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the actual extension outside of the module, and you need to export the interface...

```
module moment {
    export interface Moment {
        isWeekend(): boolean
    }
}

(<any>moment).fn.isWeekend = function() {
    this.isoWeekday() >= 6;
};
```

Comment: I've tried to apply this, but i get "moment.isWeekend is undefined" when I try to use it

Comment: It looks like with MomentJS you don't extend the prototype, but instead add to a `fn` property. I have updated the example. You also need to use a function, not an arrow-function as otherwise you will affect the scope of `this`.

Comment: My mistake was that I didn't have to change the original JavaScript code, just add the TypeScript declaration.

Comment: @Fenton I get the error: [ts] cannot use 'moment' namespace as a value.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
declare module 'moment' {
  export interface Moment {
    toTaiwaneseYear(): number;
  }
}

(moment.fn as any).toTaiwaneseYear = function () {
  const _self = this as moment.Moment;
  return _self.year() - 1911;
}
```

reference:

https://medium.com/my-life/extension-method-in-typescript-66d801488589