# Typescript: Add a function to moment.js namespace

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm trying to add extra functionality to moment.js library. I want to add a function that itself requires a moment() call in its body and I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

I'm using the latest version of Typescript and moment.js. I've tried to find a solution but I've come up with nothing. This solution ([Typescript: add function to momentjs' prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31724451/8419200)) has come close to working, I think, but still nothing.

So far what I have is:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

export namespace moment{
    interface Moment{
        myFunc(): boolean;
    }
}

(moment as any).fn.myFunc = function() {
    return moment(....);
};
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but when I try to use the moment library and myFunc I thought importing moment (import * as moment from 'moment') would be enough but myFunc isn't recognized, only the standard moment functions.

Ex. This says myFunc() isn't recognized.

```
import * as moment from 'moment'
import Moment = moment.Moment

... moment().add(...) //works
... moment().myFunc() // doesn't recognize myFunc()
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Comment: because `myFunc` does not exists in `moment`

Comment: You should import your own `moment` type, not the one exported by `moment`. So change `import * as moment from 'moment'` to `import * as moment from './moment-extended'` or something.

Comment: Okay so I changed my code to how @csander suggested but it's not working. Am I doing this right? I import `* as moment from 'moment'` and `* as myMoment from './moment.extended` in the example above and I try to call myFunc like this: 'myMoment.myFunc()' but I get  this error: Property 'myFunc' does not exist on type 'typeof "c:/Git/.../moment.extended"'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can extend `moment` to include your `myFunc` using TypeScript's [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html).

The following works for me (using TypeScript 2.4.2):

```ts
import * as moment from 'moment';

declare module "moment" {
  interface Moment {
    myFunc(): moment.Moment;
  }
}

(moment as any).fn.myFunc = function (): moment.Moment {
  console.log("Called myFunc!");
  return moment();
};

console.log(moment().myFunc().valueOf());
```

And outputs:

```
Called myFunc!
1501901308611
```

Comment: Looks good. And just to add, if you put this in a separate .ts file - just import the file after moment. `import './file';`

Comment: @puttputt saved me a lot of time. I added it in main.ts