# How can I extend moment.js and add new functions/methods to it?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, prototype, extend

In a React project, I'm using moment.js (version 2.22.2) and would like to extend it and add new functions to it in order to simplify common use cases.

I've tried several different ways of extending moment.js, but after lots of experimentation and Googling, I haven't been able to figure it out.

None of the following work:

#1:

```
import moment from 'moment';

moment.formatForDb = () => {
    return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};

export default moment;
```

#2:

```
import moment from 'moment';

moment.prototype.formatForDb = () => {
    return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};

export default moment;
```

#3:

```
import moment from 'moment';

moment.fn.formatForDb = () => {
    return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};

export default moment;
```

Does anyone know how to extend moment.js so that new functions can be added to it? Thank you.

Comment: apparently `.fn` should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514624/typescript-add-a-function-to-moment-js-namespace

Comment: Also use `= function() {` instead of `= () =>`, otherwise Moment's context doesn't get passed inside the function and `this` is not what you think it is

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I saw that same SO post, but it's for TypeScript, and I can tell you for a fact that #3 above doesn't work. Maybe `.fn` is the key, but if that's the case, then I'm probably missing something else, and I'm not familiar enough with TypeScript to just take what's in the other post and convert it to vanilla JS. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Bing, bong! Jeremy, you hit the nail on the head. I saw `function () {}` being used in other examples, and the contextual difference between that and `() => {}` with `this` in JS didn't even cross my mind. That instantly fixed it. Posting a solution below. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks to Daniel A. White and Jeremy Thille in the comments above for pointing me in the right direction.

It turns out that you do indeed need to use `.fn`, but the problem was that I was using an arrow function, as opposed to a standard function, for which the meaning of `this` is different.

As such, here's the working code:

```
import moment from 'moment';

moment.fn.formatForDb = function () {
    return this.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};

export default moment;
```

Thanks again!